# Sound effects in C# Text-to-Speech

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I'm using Microsoft Speech Synthesis in C# and I want to know if there is a way to add echo effects and other sound effects to the speech such that the speech appears to be happening in a live stadium or a room etc. Also, I want to use other voices for my code besides Microsoft Anna in Win 7 64 bit but all I found was ways to change voices using .cpl files but I did not find any free voices. I did find http://www.cepstral.com/en/personal/download which has free voice downloads but these are for older SAPI versions - will these create problems in the current installation? Any other sources to download free voices to be used in the code or even ways to make other voices such as Sam (old windows), David (Win 8) usable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about specific effects but you can choose a voice by SelectVoice(), or SelectVoiceByHints(gender, age, position, locale). Of course you can also set the rate. So you can do quite a few effects using just the Windows Speech Synthesizer. [MSDN wss](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer_methods.aspx)